# Почему отсчет времени в функции time() в php начинается с 1 января 1970 года?

Tags: php

Почему функция `time()` в php считает именно с 1 января 1970 года?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Официальная дата создания Unix - 1970 год. Поэтому ни 1 файл не может быть создан раньше 01.01.1970.

Более полное описание можно найти в статье [Wired News](http://www.wired.com/science/discoveries/news/2001/09/46651). Она объясняет, что инженеры Unix выбрали эту дату произвольно потому, что она необходима, чтобы установить единую дату начала времени, и начало 1970 года казалось наиболее удобным.

Данный вопрос уже задавался на [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26205)

Comment: ... А PHP включает обёртки ко многим сишным функциям, в частности, к `time()`.